# a slippery JSF syntax error

Tags: eclipse, jsf-2

If I try to display a JSF 2 page on Tomcat 7.0.34 with:

- jsf-api/impl 2.1.7
- el-api 2.5
- jstl 1.2

like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:cis="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/comp">

<h:head>
  <title>Prova errore di sintassi</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
  <f:view>
    <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/include/menubar.xhtml" />
    <h:form>
      <p:ajaxStatus style="width: 32px;height: 32px;" />
      <p:growl />
      <p:panel id="pannello">
    <p:focus />
    <p:messages
      showDetail="true"
      globalOnly="true" />
    <h:panelGrid columns="3">
      <p:outputLabel
        for="ckpensionat2"
        value="Pens2"
        title="tit x pens2"
        style="padding-right: 3px;  display: inline-block; min-width: 60px;" />
      <p:selectBooleanCheckbox
        id="ckpensionat2"
        value="#{miocomp.pensionato}"
        title="tit x pens2"
        valueChangeListener="#{miocomp.pensCambiato}" />
      </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
      <h:outputLabel  value="pippo" />
      </h:outputLabel>
      <p:message for="ckpensionat2" />
      <p:commandButton
        value="agg"
        update="pannello" />
    </h:panelGrid>
      </p:panel>
    </h:form>
  </f:view>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Nothing is showing!
please pay attention to the error of double closing tag

> ```
>  .../>
>  </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
>  <h:outputLabel  value="pippo" />
>  </h:outputLabel>
> ```

My questions are:

1. why `</h:outputLabel>` is evincted like a syntax error on Eclipse while `</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>` not
2. when I try to show this page I get a blank page. If I remove the error all goes fine.
3. no errors at all appears on my log view neither on tomcat 7 log dir

thanks in advance for any suggestions

Comment: Thanks BalusC (btw many compliments for your job!) for pointing the eclipse tag. It's more like an eclipse problem but it remain the fact that at run-time nobody is complaining about this mistake. No error log, only a blank page, I think it's hard to detect such an error.

Answer (score 1):

1. It is a syntax error (invalid XML) since in `<h:outputLabel  value="pippo" />
   </h:outputLabel>` you close the tag twice; once with the `/>` end tag and secondly with the `</h:outputLabel>` element. Also, `p:selectBooleanCheckbox` doesn't have `title` attribute. I'm pretty sure IDE can't validate the rest of the document because of these errors, so it only complains about the first.
2. That's normal...
3. I believe you should increase the log level or change the `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE` parameter to `Development` in your app's web.xml

Comment: As a note, in Netbeans, the XML validator complains only for the `p:selectBooleanCheckbox` invalid `title` attribute. When I correct this error, the rest show up.

Comment: I just want to point out that those errors are desired, they are there to show inappropriate behavior. The main thing is that with those errors there is no diagnose.